# Does Schur's Lemma hold in this case? Regular representations of $S_n$ over $\mathbb R$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, permutation-groups, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, modular-representation-theory, plethysm

Warning I am a physicist and I am not familiar with a lot of the machinary of representation theory.

I consider the regular representation of $\mathbb S_n$ over reals $\mathbb R$ ($\mathbb R \mathbb S_n$). I see that for the proof of Schur's lemma about the isormphisms $\phi:V \to V $ being the identity map times a scalar, when $V$ is an irreducible, one needs alebraically closed field.

$\mathbb R$ is not such a field. Is this lemma still true in this particular case?

I would be grateful if anyone can answer without too much sophisticated maths: If possible of course.

Kind regards.

Comment: The distinction between _irreducible_ and _absolutely irreducible_, as in David Hill's answer, is also discussed on Wikipedia ([Schur's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_lemma)). In this case, absolutely irreducible means irreducible even after complexification (extension of scalars from real to complex numbers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Irreducible representations of $S_n$ are *absolutely irreducible*, meaning that they remain irreducible after extension of scalars. Therefore, if $V$ is irreducible as an $\mathbb{R} S_n$-module and $\phi:V\longrightarrow V$ is any nonzero homomorphism, then
$$\phi\otimes 1:V\otimes\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow V\otimes\mathbb{C}$$
is nonzero and $V\otimes \mathbb{C}$ is irreducible. It follows that $\phi\otimes1$ is an isomorphism, hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

To read more, I suggest Gordon James' book, or the James-Kerber text.

Comment: Is there a way to prove absolute irreducibility without having to find all irreps?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think the answer to your question is no, but that is because there is a very nice way of describing the irreducible complex reptns of $S_n$ in terms of Young diagrams, and it is a by-product of this theory that yields the result that they can all be written over the integers.